# Find where a class is instantiated in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for how to quickly find where a class is instantiated in Eclipse. I know that you can use Search and look for `new myClassName(`  in `*java` files. I'm looking for an option where right click somewhere in the class definition to find where it is instantiated in the project or a keyboard shortcut of some type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Highlight the constructor in the class, then use <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+G</kbd> to search for occurrences of the constructor being used.